# list row of foreign key model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i have a question with the next model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id_product  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title       = models.CharField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Orders(models.Model):
    id_order    = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    date        = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

How can I list all product and the last order of each product ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to know only last order's date then you can use Product.objects.annotate(last_order=Max('orders__date')).all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select all products and the last order of each product ?

```
for i in Products.objects.all():
    i,Orders.objects.filter(product=i).latest('date')
```

Comment: hi, how can I use in the template or list with the view ? thanks

Comment: just saved it in a `dict` and pass it to templates eg:- `def products_and_its_lastorder(request): prod_order=[] for i in Products.objects.all(): prod_order.append([i,Orders.objects.filter(product=i).latest('date')])  return render(request,<template path>, {'product_order':prod_order})` you can use this is template like `{% for po in product_order %} product:{{ po.0.title }} last order:{{ po.1.description }} {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
>>> for product in Product.objects.all():
        print product, product.orders_set.latest('date')
```

For each product, you can access set of orders as `product.orders_set` which is relationship manager using which you can do queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your classes in the singular, *Order* as opposed to *Orders*.

If you are using postgresql, you can do this:

```
Orders.objects.order_by('-date').distinct(product)
```

Otherwise:

```
[(p,p.orders_set.latest('date')) for p in Product.objects.all()]
```